# Swift iOS app Archive error

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I'm following my book to release my app.

so, I want Archive my app but my app fire error like the picture below.

I have realm framework for using Db. and also have kakaolink(api) framework.
What can i do to solve this?

[image: error picture]
[image]

Comment: Are you adding any framework as Embedded Framework in your project?

Comment: @AravindAR In my project General, it have RealmSwift.framework and Realm.frameWork

Comment: I just wanted to know whether you have added any frameworks under Embedded binaries section?

Comment: @AravindAR I think it have please check question i update my question

Comment: I have added an answer which worked for me when I had a similar issue with some other framework. It would be great if you could try that and confirm whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following run script to your Build Phases section

```
bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
```

This step is required to work around an [App Store submission bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216) when archiving universal binaries.

Please make sure that you are adding the run script below the Embedded Binaries in Build Phases section.

Try archiving the project, again if the error exists try the following steps.

- Remove the corresponding framework and run-scripts that are creating
  the problem. Then compile and run the code.
- Add the embedded framework first and then add the run-script. Please
  make sure the order in the build phases should be like the embedded
  framework above the run script which you use to select the correct
  architecture.

Comment: It is work!!! really really really really really really really really really really Thanks.... haha
i'm not good at english and beginner at swift.

Comment: Thanks for appreciate my bad english :)